# Microsoft Power Apps - Get other user's calendar

Tags: powerapps

I was wondering if there is a way to get other user's calendars so I can select one shared calendar and then pick up all events in a specific time range and do something with it.

I created a combobox with items property:

```html
Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm: ComboBox.SearchText})
```

and now I have another combobox where if i were to use in items this:

```html
Office365Outlook.CalendarGetTables().value
```

I get my own calendars but I don't see how to connect my first combobox with user selection and the second combobox.

We are talking about only shared calendars that someone has access to.

Please advise